# Discord API: Get Application Name

Tags: json, discord, payload

I'm currently programming a Discord RPC client, which shows a preview of the Presence.
I found out, that with "https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/applications/[appid]/assets" you get the asset id from the application and with it the image using "https://cdn.discordapp.com/app-assets/[appid]/[assetid].png". But how do i get the application name with the client id?

Comment: Hi! I am having the same problem, have you found any answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not @NicoHalpe

Comment: I've just found a way, but it is not exactly getting the app name from a url.

Answer (score 0):

I have this class, which sets AppName in customStatus class

```
class getAppName
    {
        static DiscordRpcClient client;
        public getAppName(string AppId)
        {
            client = new DiscordRpcClient(AppId);
            client.Initialize();
            client.OnReady += OnClientReady;
            client.OnPresenceUpdate += Client_OnPresenceUpdate;
        }

        private void Client_OnPresenceUpdate(object sender, PresenceMessage args)
        {
            customStatus.AppName = (args.Name);
            client.ClearPresence();
            client.Dispose();
        }

        private void OnClientReady(object sender, ReadyMessage args)
        {
            client.SetPresence(new RichPresence { });
        }
    }
```

And in customStatus class:

```
public static string AppName { get; set; }
```

And:

```
new getAppName("AppId");
var oldName = AppName;

//this is to wait until the new appname is set
while (oldName == AppName) {}

string newAppname = AppName;
```

Hope it works for you!